# Need to show a countdown timer in post loop after date for upcoming posts

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to show a countdown timer for upcoming posts. I am using JavaScript with PHP to achieve it. I am passing a PHP variable value in JavaScript function. Can you see the code and help me?
My Code:

```
<span><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> <?php echo get_the_date();?></span>
<?php $dtimer = get_the_date(); ?>
<span><i class='fa fa-calendar-o'></i><p id='timer-diff'></p></span> 
<script>                        
                // Set the date we're counting down to
                var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $dtimer; ?>").getTime();

                // Update the count down every 1 second
                var x = setInterval(function() {

                    // Get todays date and time
                    var now = new Date().getTime();

                    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
                    var distance = countDownDate - now;

                    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                    // Output the result in an element with id="timer-diff"
                    document.getElementById("timer-diff").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
                    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

                    // If the count down is over, write some text 
                    if (distance < 0) {
                        clearInterval(x);
                        document.getElementById("timer-diff").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
                    }
                }, 1000);
                </script>
```

[image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrN38.png)

Comment: Please update your question (don't reply here), with an example of the result you're getting with this code as well as an example of the result you expect. What do you want the countdown to be in? seconds? minutes? hours? days?

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What is the specific issue with your code that you need help with? Are you getting an error, is it giving an unexpected result, is it failing to run?

Comment: @FluffyKitten yes the js code is not running. I need a countdown timer for that schedule posts till the published date. Go here tokenschedule.com I want to show my timer only for Upcoming posts and under the date. Like if date is 15/9/2017 then timer will be shown under it in Days:hours:Min:Sec remaining to publish this post.

Comment: "Not running" still tells us nothing... we aren't mind readers. Are you getting errors in the console? Have you tried debugging it yourself? Check the errors, print out debugging messages, comment out the code and add it back bit by bit... you need to do a bit of basic debugging yourself. When you more information about the *specific* problem, we might be able to help then.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't clear in your question as to how granular the countdown should be; Hours, days, etc.

If you can supply a standard date format, or a javascript timestamp (milliseconds since January 1st, 1970) you could use MomentJS to determine the "relative time". With this relative time you can determine the number of seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks or months until the specified date. With this, it would be easy to prefix the string with "remaining". As in:

> 7 days remaining

Comment: I need a countdown timer for that schedule posts till the published date. Go here http://tokenschedule.com/    I want to show my timer only for Upcoming posts and under the date. Like if date is 15/9/2017 then timer will be shown under it in Days:hours:Min:Sec remaining to publish this post.
Issue is my JS code is not running inside wordpress files.

Comment: Please update your original question with the details